# Spring Em.persist() not inserting on testing db setup

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jpa, persistence

I'm attempting to run some tests on my Spring web app and it seems I'm having some issues initially inserting records in a DB to use my tests with. My setup is as follows:

Unit Test Setup which extends TestBase:

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    setupBase();
    configurationDao = (ConfigurationDao)ctx.getBean("configDao");       
    setupReasons(configurationDao.getEm());
}
```

TestBase:

```
public class TestBase {

    protected ApplicationContext ctx;

    public void setupBase() {
        ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
    }

    public static String getRandomUUIDStyleId() {
        return UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(0, 24);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void setupReasons(EntityManager em) {
        DateTime now = new DateTime();
        for (Reason reason : Reasons.values()) {
            ReasonEntity r = new ReasonEntity();
            r.setId(reason.ordinal());
            r.setReason(reason.name());
            em.persist(r);
        }
    }
}
```

BaseDao which Configuration extends:

```
public abstract class BaseDao<T extends EntityBase> implements Dao<T> {

    @PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager em;
    protected Class<T> entityClass;

    @Transactional
    public T findById(long id) {
        return em.find(entityClass, id);
    }

    @Transactional
    public List<T> findAll() {
        Query query = em.createQuery("from " + entityClass.getName());
        return (List<T>) query.getResultList();
    }

    @Transactional
    public T persistOrMerge(T entity) {
        if (entity.getId() == null || entity.getId() == 0) {
            //System.out.println("Persisting: "+entity.toString());
            em.persist(entity);
        } else {
            if (!em.contains(entity)) {
                //System.out.println("Merging: "+entity.toString());
                return em.merge(entity);
            }
        }
        return entity;
    }

    public void remove(T entity) {
        em.remove(entity);
    }

    public EntityManager getEm() {
        return em;
    }
}
```

applicationContext.xml:

```
<bean id="configDao" class="ConfigurationDao" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean" >
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="TEST-pu" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" proxy-target-class="true"  />
```

While setupReasons "appears" to be persisting it never inserts the data into the MySql table (seen through hibernate showsql property) and I can't seem to understand why. Thanks in advance for your help and if you need anything else from me I'm more than happy to provide.

Answer (score 0):

Despite the fact that setupReasons() is marked `@Transactional`, I don't see anything to make me think a transaction is being started for it. Without a transaction, nothing will be written. You might want to [read up on the Spring test framework](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testing-tx).

Comment: Are you referring to em.getTransaction.begin() / commit()? To my understanding the @Transactional annotation performs this on the method, am I wrong in assuming this?

Comment: @Transactional isn't magic. You have to have something to scan for and process the annotation, such as the Spring test framework, which I linked in my answer. Nothing in the code you posted would activate it, and therefore no transaction would ever be started.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this tutorial to make your test classes transaction aware using spring:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/testing.html

Use p6spy to inspect what is exactly being sent to the database, including start and commit transaction statements.

p6spy | http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-display-hibernate-sql-parameter-values-solution/

Answer (score 0):

For someone who still is facing this issue, just put the annotation @TransactionConfiguration in your class and that's it!

Check it out on [@TransactionConfiguration](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/transaction/TransactionConfiguration.html)